# How do I nest an array of items dividing them by their first value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a div filled with buttons. The value of these buttons represent widht and height of a product. I'm trying to split up the buttons, sorting them by their width, which is the first value in the html.

So this:

```
<div id="flagSize">
    <button id="0">100x200cm</button>
    <button id="1">100x250cm</button>
    <button id="2">100x300cm</button>
    <button id="3">100x350cm</button>
    <button id="4">100x400cm</button>
    <button id="5">110x300cm</button>
    <button id="6">120x300cm</button>
    <button id="7">120x350cm</button>
    <button id="8">120x400cm</button>
    <button id="9">140x400cm</button>
    <button id="10">150x400cm</button>
</div>
```

Has to become this:

```
<div id="flagSize">
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="0">100x200cm</button>
        <button id="1">100x250cm</button>
        <button id="2">100x300cm</button>
        <button id="3">100x350cm</button>
        <button id="4">100x400cm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="5">110x300cm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="6">120x300cm</button>
        <button id="7">120x350cm</button>
        <button id="8">120x400cm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="9">140x400cm</button>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <button id="10">150x400cm</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

To do this I figured I first have to get the content of the button, splitting it at the X. I then put this value in to an array combined with the ID of the element.

```
var orderSizes = [];

$('#flagSize button').each(function(){
    var widthValue = $(this).html();
    widthValue = widthValue.split('x');
    var orderItem = [widthValue[0],$(this).attr('id')]
    orderSizes.push(orderItem);
});

console.log(orderSizes);
```

I now have to check the values of this array and if they are the same as other items in the array, put them together in a div with the class buttonGroup. This is the part where I'm stuck.

Any help with this, or a different, better aproach would be greatly appreciated.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ldwx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
//a cache holder to hold the wrappers to that it can be reused
var wrappers = {};

$('#flagSize button').each(function () {
    var widthValue = $.trim($(this).html());
    widthValue = widthValue.split('x')[0];
    var wrapper = wrappers[widthValue];
    //if the wrapper does not exists create one and add it after the current element
    if (!wrapper) {
        wrappers[widthValue] = wrapper = $('<div class="buttonGroup"></div>').insertAfter(this);
    }
    //move the element to the respective wrapper
    wrapper.append(this)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jLFAe/)

Comment: An extra step might be needed if OP is wanting the groups sorted. Because if say `120x200cm` is the first button, the `120` buttons will be listed before the `100` buttons.

Comment: This is excelent, thank you very much!
@PatrickEvans The buttons are sorted before being supplied so no extra sorting is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript ability to store custom keys for arrays and jquery ability to iterate through them.

Because widths are numbers, it will create an array up to the size of the highest width and the iteration will go through them in order.

```
var orderSizes = [];
$('#flagSize button').each(function(){
  var widthValue = $(this).html();
  widthValue = widthValue.split('x');
  var key = widthValue[0];
  var val = $(this).attr('id');
  if(orderSizes[key]) {// If it is defined, we push the id to the existinga array
    orderSizes[key].push(val);
  } else {             // Else we create the array
    orderSizes[key] = [val];
  }
});

// Now we iterate through the key/values pairs of the orderSize
$.each(orderSizes, function(width, ids) {
  if(ids != undefined) { // For widths numbers without buttons, we should not create a div.
    var div = $('<div class="buttonGroup" id="width'+width+'"/>');
    $.each(ids, function(key, id) {
      $("#"+id).appendTo($(div));     // attaches the button to its new parent.
    });
    div.appendTo($("#flagSize")); // Inserts the div to the top-level.
  }
});
```

You can try it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ldwx/4/)